# Calculate new columns from values in existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "customer": ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'],
        "contract_year": [2018, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2019],
        "amount": [3000, 1000, 3000, 6000, 6000],
        "term": [3, 1, 2, 3, 3]
    }
)

    customer    contract_year   amount  term
0   c1          2018            3000    3
1   c2          2020            1000    1
2   c3          2019            3000    2
3   c4          2018            6000    3
4   c5          2019            6000    3
```

My goal is: for each customer, split the amount by a number of "term" years; for example:
customer c1, will pay

```
df["amount"]/df["term"]
```

for the next "term" years starting from "contract_year". These amounts should be in new columns for each payment year.

The final result should look like:

```
    customer    contract_year   amount  term    2018   2019   2020    2021
0   c1          2018            3000    3       1000   1000   1000
1   c2          2020            1000    1                     1000
2   c3          2019            3000    2              1500   1500
3   c4          2018            6000    3       2000   2000   2000
4   c5          2019            6000    3              2000   2000    2000
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do:

```
s = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['term']))
s['val']  = s['amount'].floordiv(s['term'])
s['year'] = s['contract_year'] + s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()

s.pivot_table('val', [*df.columns], 'year', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

**Details**:

`reindex` the dataframe by using `index.repeat`:

```
print(s)

  customer  contract_year  amount  term
0       c1           2018    3000     3
0       c1           2018    3000     3
0       c1           2018    3000     3
1       c2           2020    1000     1
2       c3           2019    3000     2
2       c3           2019    3000     2
3       c4           2018    6000     3
3       c4           2018    6000     3
3       c4           2018    6000     3
4       c5           2019    6000     3
4       c5           2019    6000     3
4       c5           2019    6000     3
```

divide `amount` by `term` in order to split the amount evenly between the number of `term` years:

```
print(s)

  customer  contract_year  amount  term   val
0       c1           2018    3000     3  1000
0       c1           2018    3000     3  1000
0       c1           2018    3000     3  1000
1       c2           2020    1000     1  1000
2       c3           2019    3000     2  1500
2       c3           2019    3000     2  1500
3       c4           2018    6000     3  2000
3       c4           2018    6000     3  2000
3       c4           2018    6000     3  2000
4       c5           2019    6000     3  2000
4       c5           2019    6000     3  2000
4       c5           2019    6000     3  2000
```

Create sequential counter per `level=0` group by using `cumcount`, then add this counter to `contract_year` in order to generate next term years:

```
print(s)

  customer  contract_year  amount  term   val  year
0       c1           2018    3000     3  1000  2018
0       c1           2018    3000     3  1000  2019
0       c1           2018    3000     3  1000  2020
1       c2           2020    1000     1  1000  2020
2       c3           2019    3000     2  1500  2019
2       c3           2019    3000     2  1500  2020
3       c4           2018    6000     3  2000  2018
3       c4           2018    6000     3  2000  2019
3       c4           2018    6000     3  2000  2020
4       c5           2019    6000     3  2000  2019
4       c5           2019    6000     3  2000  2020
4       c5           2019    6000     3  2000  2021
```

Use `pivot_table` to reshape the dataframe:

```
year customer  contract_year  amount  term    2018    2019    2020    2021
0          c1           2018    3000     3  1000.0  1000.0  1000.0     NaN
1          c2           2020    1000     1     NaN     NaN  1000.0     NaN
2          c3           2019    3000     2     NaN  1500.0  1500.0     NaN
3          c4           2018    6000     3  2000.0  2000.0  2000.0     NaN
4          c5           2019    6000     3     NaN  2000.0  2000.0  2000.0
```